# Django Pagination: switch between paginated/non-paginated ListView

Tags: python, django, pagination

I'm trying to elaborate a smart way to switch between a paginated template and a non-paginated one.

I already have a working paginator and I was thinking of adding a button next to it that read "Show all results" that linked to a non-paginated list, from there then there would be another button to go back to the paginated list.

**1) Easy Solution**

Use 2 ListViews with different assignations of the attribute *paginate_by* (django default to set pagination), but since I have many lists in my project it wouldn't be convenient (not much smart either).

**2) Solution I'm stuck on**

Write a Mixin (that will later be extended by my ListViews) to set the variable *paginate_by* based on a condition and then add some useful variables to the context :

```
class PaginationMixin:
    no_pagination = False
    no_pagination_url = ''

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
     # overwrite django method
        if self.no_pagination:
            return None
        else:
            return super().get_paginate_by(queryset)

    def get_no_pagination_url(self):
        return self.no_pagination_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['no_pagination'] = self.no_pagination
        context['no_pagination_url'] = self.get_no_pagination_url()
        return context

 class MyListView(PaginationMixin, ListView):
     #...
     def get_no_pagination_url(self):
         return reverse('mylist_urlname')
```

PROBLEM: I don't know how to set the *no_pagination*  variable from the template. Is there some way to do this?

Thanks for the help.

UPDATED SOLUTION (edited from @hi-lan solution):
This way it will show all results and also keep urlparams (from filters or other) if present.

```
class PaginationMixin:

    toggle_pagination = False
    toggle_pagination_url = ''
    no_pagination = False
    view_name = ''
    urlparams_dict = {}

    def get(self, request, page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        #store current GET params and pop 'page' key
        self.urlparams_dict = request.GET            
        self.urlparams_dict.pop('page', None)

        page = page or request.GET.get('page', '1')
        if page == 'all':
            page = self.paginate_by = None
            self.no_pagination = True
        return super().get(request, page=page, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        if self.no_pagination:
            return None
        else:
            return super().get_paginate_by(queryset)

    def get_toggle_pagination_url(self):
        # variables to set in view to toggle this mixin
        if self.toggle_pagination and self.view_name:
            if not self.no_pagination:
                extra = {'page': 'all'}
                self.urlparams_dict.update(extra)
            else:
                self.urlparams_dict.pop('page', None)
            # url keeps track of urlparams adds page=all if toggled
            self.toggle_pagination_url = reverse(self.view_name) + '?' + urlencode(self.urlparams_dict)
        return self.toggle_pagination_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['toggle_pagination_url'] = self.get_toggle_pagination_url()
        context['toggle_pagination'] = self.toggle_pagination
        return context
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at data flow back from user to indicate non pagination. The only way I can think of is to use special page number. There are two options, depends on which way you config urls.py.

- In case of `path('objects/page<int:page>/',
  PaginatedView.as_view()),` special number is 0 (as normal page number
  is started from 1).
- In case of `/objects/?page=3`, special number can be `all`.

In either case, we need to override `get` method as it is where we can retrieve user's selection.

```py
class PaginationMixin:
    no_pagination = False
    view_name = ''

    def get(self, request, page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        page = page or request.GET.get('page', '1')
        if page in ['0', 'all']:
            page = self.paginate_by = None
        else: pass
        return super().get(request, page=page, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        # overwrite django method
        if self.no_pagination:
            return None
        else:
            return super().get_paginate_by(queryset)

    def get_no_pagination_url(self):
        # For using path
        extra = {'page': '0'}
        no_pagination_url = reverse(self.view_name, kwargs=extra)
        # For using query params
        extra = {'page': 'all'}
        no_pagination_url = reverse(self.view_name) + '?' + urlencode(extra)
        return no_pagination_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['no_pagination'] = self.no_pagination
        context['no_pagination_url'] = self.get_no_pagination_url()
        return context


class MyListView(PaginationMixin, ListView):
    view_name = 'mylist_urlname'
    #...
```

Comment: I'm using query params for pagination and this solution fits perfectly what I was looking for ! I'll test it out a little more for some exceptions and use cases (i.e. pagination integrity when using filters) but it seems is doing all right for now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying the UPDATED SOLUTION of gccallie with this view :

```html
class StageTempList(PaginationMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    view_name = 'stagetemp-list'
    table_class = StageTempTable
    model = StageTemp
    filterset_class = StageTempFilter
    template_name = 'stage/stagetemp_list.html'
    paginate_by = 30
    strict = False
```

But when get_paginate_by return None, I get 25 rows.
Django version 2.1.2

UPDATE : the PaginationMixin Class I use

```js
class PaginationMixin:
    no_pagination = False
    view_name = ''

    def get(self, request, page=None, *args, **kwargs):
        page = page or request.GET.get('page', '1')
        if page in ['0', 'all']:
            page = self.paginate_by = None
            self.no_pagination = True
        else: pass
        return super().get(request, page=page, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_paginate_by(self, queryset):
        # overwrite django method
        if self.no_pagination:
            return None
        else:
            return super().get_paginate_by(queryset)

    def get_no_pagination_url(self):
        extra = {'page': 'all'}
        no_pagination_url = reverse(self.view_name) + '?' + urlencode(extra)
        return no_pagination_url

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['no_pagination'] = self.no_pagination
        context['no_pagination_url'] = self.get_no_pagination_url()
        return context
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem, could you be more specific? Do you mean that it gets paginated by 25 instead of 30?

Comment: Yes I get 25 whatever I set in paginate_by in the views.